# I Have two Websites which i want to run from one ip with Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

below is my conf file

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;

   server_name _;
root /var/www/html;


   index index.html index.htm;

    location /test1/ {
       alias  /var/www/html/test1;
            try_files $uri  /index.html;}

  location /test2/ {
      alias /var/www/html/test2;
       try_files $uri /index.html;}}
```

if anyone help me with this
i'm getting the 404 error in web browser for this.

Comment: two separate websites, or one website with two subfolders on it? site.com/test1/ & dite.com/test2/ ?

Comment: one ip with two websites like http://localhost/test1/    &  http://localhost/test2/

Answer (score 0):

For two SEPARATE websites like site1.com & site2.com, you need to specify two separate `server_name` directives eachin it's own `server{}` block:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name site1.com;
   root /var/www/html/site1;

   index index.html index.htm;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name site2.com;
   root /var/www/html/site2;

   index index.html index.htm;
}
```

For a single host with two folders, example:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name site1.com;
   root /var/www/html/site1;

   index index.html index.htm;

// here without specifying `root` it will use relative to
// the more general root above, so: /var/www/html/site1/folder1/

 location ~ /folder1 {
   index index.html index.htm;
}

// or you can specify `root` within the `location`,
// so it will load index from: /var/www/html/site1/folder2

 location ~ /folder1 {
   root /var/www/html/site1/folder2;
   index index.html index.htm;
}



}
```

Comment: same error with this in web browser...  While in my nginx error.log is showing `/var/www/html/test1/test2/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)`  this

Comment: I do not have `test1` nor `test2` in my config, where did you get that from?

Comment: they are in my config ...im using one ip with two different subfolders/websites.

Comment: Well I asked earlier. Subfolder is NOT a website... so if you have all of those, you will be getting errors.